# Django 2.1.7: Makemigrations command result: "No change detected in app"

Tags: django

(I am aware that a number of Django users have had the same issue.

I have looked at a number of solutions online but none has worked for me so far.)

I have set up my `apps.py`, `settings.py` and `models.py` files as explained in Django official  tutorial (please see the 3 files below).

When I enter in the terminal:

```
$ python3 manage.py makemigrations munichliving_app
```

It returns:

> No changes detected in app 'munichliving_app'

(file settings.py) in INSTALLED_APP --> I added and tested both one at a time:
'munichliving_app' and 
'munichliving_app.apps.MunichLivingConfig'

apps.py file:   https://pastebin.com/raw/qaYy1x44

setting.py file: https://pastebin.com/raw/cSsbfPsx

models.py: https://pastebin.com/raw/U0QeM16k

Django official tutorial states that I should see something along the lines of:

Migrations for 'polls':

polls/migrations/0001_initial.py:

```
- Create model Choice
- Create model Question
- Add field question to choice
```

Thank you.

Comment: Are you models.py in the same folder than settings.py? If that is the case, run `django-admin startapp randomappname`, add `randomappname` yor your installed apps, remove `munichliving_app` from there, move your models to `randomappname` and try again. The case there is you don't actually have a `munichliving_app`

Comment: Look at the directory structure described in [the tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial01/#writing-your-first-django-app-part-1), both after `startproject` and `startapp`.

Comment: Thanks. Here is my files structure: https://ibb.co/0VW7km1 Could you specify exactly what I need to do ?

Comment: OK I understand better now.

Answer (score 2):

Your app is `munichliving` (the module that contains `models.py`), but you have `munichliving_app` in your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting. The `munichlivin_app` is the project folder (the one that contains `settings.py`). It doesn't normally contain models so you shouldn't usually have to add it to `INSTALLED_APPS` or make migrations for it.

Replace `'munichliving_app'` with `'munichliving'` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Next, I would remove your `apps.py` because it doesn't appear to be used. If you do keep it, then change it to `name='munichliving', then use`'munichliving.apps.MunichLivingConfig'`in`INSTALLED_APPS`.

Finally, create migrations with

```
./manage.py makemigrations munichliving
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
python manage.py migrate --fake appname
```

Or delete the migration folder in your app, go to the database and delete the file in `django_migrations` table, then migrate again:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```